# Movable control/panel with using ajax?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, dotnetnuke

I need to create a movable / dragablle panel/control without using ajax and then include it in .net nuke .

Can anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you can still user regular Javascript even if you aren't allowed AJAX?

I would check this link out: http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/drag/